# extracting newest date from column with multiple dates in each cell

Tags: r

I have the following dummy data frame:

```
structure(list(id = 1:10, dates = c("2018-07-02, 2018-06-28", 
"2018-08-22", "2018-08-06, 2018-07-31", "2018-03-08", "2018-02-22, 2018-02-19", 
"2018-07-04, 2018-07-06", "2018-06-26, 2018-06-22", "2018-01-18, 2018-01-24", 
"2018-06-05, 2018-06-14", "2018-01-18")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to convert all entries in the "dates" column to date, then select the newest one, and remove all other dates in that cell.

I have tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reprex)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

test_df %>%
    mutate(dates = dates %>%
            str_extract_all("[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+") %>%
            map(ymd) %>%
            map_lgl(~ any(max(.))))
```

But somehow this converts all entries in each cell to a number instead of proper dates.

What I want to end up with:

```
id dates
1 2018-07-02
2 2018-08-22            
3 2018-08-06
4 2018-03-08            
5 2018-02-22
6 2018-07-06
7 2018-06-26
8 2018-01-24
9 2018-06-14
10 2018-01-18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scan` in the fields, take the largest and convert to `Date` class.

```
library(dplyr)

scan_max <- function(x) {
  max(scan(text = x, what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE))
}
test_df %>%
  mutate(dates = as.Date(sapply(dates, scan_max)))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id dates     
   <int> <date>    
 1     1 2018-07-02
 2     2 2018-08-22
 3     3 2018-08-06
 4     4 2018-03-08
 5     5 2018-02-22
 6     6 2018-07-06
 7     7 2018-06-26
 8     8 2018-01-24
 9     9 2018-06-14
10    10 2018-01-18
```

It could also be written like this:

```
scan_max <- . %>% 
  scan(text = ., what = "", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE) %>%
  max

test_df %>%
  mutate(dates = dates %>% sapply(scan_max) %>% as.Date)
```

Comment: Neat and clean - love one liners! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(dates = str_split(dates, ", ") %>%
                map(sort, decreasing = TRUE) %>%
                map_chr(1) %>%
                as.Date)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id dates     
   <int> <date>    
 1     1 2018-07-02
 2     2 2018-08-22
 3     3 2018-08-06
 4     4 2018-03-08
 5     5 2018-02-22
 6     6 2018-07-06
 7     7 2018-06-26
 8     8 2018-01-24
 9     9 2018-06-14
10    10 2018-01-18
```

Answer (score 1):

I use three mutates:

1. splits the strings by comma
2. converts strings to dates
3. keeps only the newest date

Then this is it:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:10, dates = c("2018-07-02, 2018-06-28", 
                                    "2018-08-22", "2018-08-06, 2018-07-31", "2018-03-08", "2018-02-22, 2018-02-19", 
                                    "2018-07-04, 2018-07-06", "2018-06-26, 2018-06-22", "2018-01-18, 2018-01-24", 
                                    "2018-06-05, 2018-06-14", "2018-01-18")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

library(tidyr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(dates = stri_split_fixed(dates, ", ")) %>% 
  mutate(dates = rapply(dates, as.Date, how = "list")) %>% 
  mutate(dates = lapply(dates, function(x) {
    sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1]
  })) %>% 
  unnest(dates)

> df_new
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id dates     
   <int> <date>    
 1     1 2018-07-02
 2     2 2018-08-22
 3     3 2018-08-06
 4     4 2018-03-08
 5     5 2018-02-22
 6     6 2018-07-06
 7     7 2018-06-26
 8     8 2018-01-24
 9     9 2018-06-14
10    10 2018-01-18
```

Another option with map instead of the two `apply`s:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(dates = stri_split_fixed(dates, ", ")) %>% 
  mutate(dates = map(dates, function(x) {
    x <- as.Date(x)
    sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1]
  })) %>%
  unnest(dates)

df_new
```